# Creating batch file for mapping network drive (off site)

Tags: batch-file, networking, network-drive

What i'm trying to do is access a network drive from my schools campus we have webdav that allows us to map it directly to the computer using the windows os. I'm trying to do this a different way using a batch file. Right now im using the net  use N:..... but it only seems to work when I'm on campus. as long as im on the network that the n drive is hosted on. when i try to use it at home it tells me that there is an issue "System error 59 occurred" and "An unexpected network error occurred." Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like it is behaving correctly.. The `net use` command will only work if the network share you're connecting to is accessible on the current network connection(s). When the batch file/net use command fails, can you connect to the drive using another method?

Comment: Yes, I can connect using windows when you right click computer and map a network drive. which is why i was a little confused as to why net use wouldnt work but your answer kind of clears that up. Is there anyway to replicate what the the network drive mapping wizard does in a batch file? the other question i have is that I am trying to use it on a network drive that has the username built into the url for the drive. is there a way to ask for the username and add the username to the url perhaps using user input or a variable of some sort?

Comment: I'm not sure about the difference between the GUI and `net use`. I can only think that maybe `net use` behaves differently when the machines are on different subnets? Do they match? (Run `ipconfig /all` on both machines to compare the network information of each..)

Comment: As far as getting user input from a batch file, that is easy enough. Use the following line to prompt the user with `User name: ` and save the result into the `uservar` environment variable: `set /P "uservar=User name: "`

Comment: would i just then have it so that its net use N: https://........../uservar

Comment: normally the url would be https://<url>/username    so using the variable would just replace username with the uservar?

Comment: hmm when i use set /P "uservar = User name: " and then put the url as https://<url>/uservar it comes back with wrong url but the url is correct.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with batch files so, please excuse me if I am detailing too much or explaining to simplistically :). Make sure you put % around your variable such as: `set "url=https://website/%uservar%"`.

Comment: Perfect that worked! thanks, now my next step is to expand this batch file and have it use if and goto. There are 2 different urls 1 for students and 1 for faculty and staff, im trying to make it so that if the user presses "1" it will ask for username the same as before but now itll "goto" the student url and if the user types "2" it'll ask for the username same as before but now it'll goto the faculty url

Comment: So i've gotten decently far. im using choice to have the user type Y or N and take them to the specific url the issue im having now is that it is saying that System error 1223 has occurred saying that I canceled the operation but im not sure why..any thoughts?